# How to implement usePrevious in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I took this code from React documentation. But apparently, I am not using it right.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function usePreviousState(state) {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = state;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

This is my functional component:

```
export default function personInfo({ data, setData }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const prevData = usePreviousState(data);

  function handleFieldChange(event) {
    setData({
      ...data,
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  async function handleSaveClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = normalizeData(data);
    try {
      if (JSON.stringify(data) !== JSON.stringify(prevData)) {
        await updatePeronInfo(formData);
        alert('Successfully updated personal information!');
      } else {
        await createPersonInfo(data);
        alert('Your personal information has been saved!');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      handleErrors(error);
    }
  }
```

The first problem is, that I cannot post the information, it is always giving me POST and PATCH, but it is throwing 404 error Page not found, so it did not create or update the information at all. If I change the if statement from `(JSON.stringify(data) !== JSON.stringify(prevData))` to `(JSON.stringify(data) === JSON.stringify(prevData))` somehow it manage to POST the data. But later on if I want to update the info it appears that it is trying to execute createPersonInfo, which leads to an error 500 Internal Server Error because it is already created. Any idea what I am doing wrong, and what I am missing in the "IF LOGIC". Apparently, prevData is undefined at the beginning. How should I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add simple check:

```
if (typeof prevData !== 'undefined') {
       if (JSON.stringify(data) !== JSON.stringify(prevData)) {...}
} else {...}
```